# Need to replace selected html tags from string in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to replace few selected html tags from string .
Like for example let the string :

```
<B><SMALL>DSD-DNPH Color Cap Insert</SMALL></B>
```

and I did in following way :

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(name_text, '<[SMALL>]+>|<[/SMALL>]+>', '')
```

But I want to remove all selected html tags like: `<B>`, `<SMALL>` and `<FONT>` .

Can you please suggest me to do this in single line for multiple selector.

Comment: And did that work? You say you DID IT that way. I don't believe you. `[SMALL]` will match ONE CHARACTER, `S`, `M`, `A` or `L`. It would delete the character `S` in `DSD_NDPH`. So... ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following construct to get rid of tags like constructs from string:

```
regexp_replace(name_text, '<.*?>')
```

Comment: Hi @sebz thanks for your quick reply.but i want to remove only 3 html tags not all ie <B>,<SMALL> and <FONT>.Can you suggest any other solution.

Comment: Hi, In that case you can have 3 nested calls to replace each tag: `REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(name_text, '<[SMALL>]+>|<[/SMALL>]+>', ''), '<[B>]+>|<[/B>]+>', ''), '<[FONT>]+>|<[/FONT>]+>', '')` Is this feasible?

Comment: Awesome @sebz .Thanks for your help